# Behavior of an $L^2$ function close to $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, hilbert-spaces

This question is related to that [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560438/integral-behavior-with-small-o-notation) concerning the solutions to a resolvent equation coming out of an eigenvalue problem I am working on.

Claim that I think is true: if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, such that $f(x)/{\sqrt{x}} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$, then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=0$.

In other words
$$
\text{If }f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)\cap C^0(0,\infty)\text{ and }\int_0^1 \frac{|f|^2}{x}dx<\infty,\text{ then }\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=0.
$$

It is easy to prove that $\liminf_{x\to 0^+} |f|=0$, but I cannot rule out $\limsup_{x\to 0^+} |f|>0$.

Comment: Why do you take an integral over $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Ilya The "rest" of the integral, from 1 to $\infty$, converges automatically because $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$. All what I need to use is the integrability at $x=0$. I could have taken the integral over any interval of the form $(0,a)$, with $a>0$, and that would have worked for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a  continuous function $f$ such that  $0 \leq f \le1 $  vanishing  at $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and $\frac 1 {n^{2}}-\frac 1 {n^{4}}$ , with $f(x) =1$ at the mid-point of the interval $(\frac 1 {n^{2}}-\frac 1 {n^{4}},\frac 1 {n^{2}})$, for each $n>1$. This is a  counter-example to your claim.

Comment: Thank you for the nice example.