# Integral of a continuous function at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, improper-integrals, approximation-theory

This is part of a series of questions of mine that came up when looking at the solutions to the resolvent equations related an eigenvalue problem I am working on. See for example that [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561114/behavior-of-an-l2-function-close-to-x-0).

My claim: if $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere such that $f(0)=0$, then
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{|f(x)|}{x} dx <\infty.
$$

I think it is true. I am just not sure how to prove it. But then, someone might prove me wrong by providing a counter-example.

Comment: The function needs to be continuous.

Comment: In other words, $x=1$ is not important. I am only interested to know if $f(x)/x$ is integrable through $x=0$ if $f(0)=0$. So, I could have made my integral on the interval $(0,1/2)$ for example.

Comment: Continuous where?  I assumed you just wanted continuity in the open interval $(0,1)$, so $f(x)=\frac x{1-x}$ would work.

Comment: How about $f(x) = x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, with this function being defined to be $0$ at $x = 0$? You could probably show that $\int_{0}^{1} |\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)| \ dx$ diverges.

Comment: Everywhere. I added that word. I am only interested in knowing if $f(x)/x$ is integrable though $x=0$.

Comment: The integral of $\sin(1/x)$ on the interval $(0,1)$ converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.
As a counter-example, let $f(x) = \lvert\log x\rvert^{-1}$ with $f(0) = 0$.